# Qualified name lookup inside the class scope

Tags: c++, class, scope, language-lawyer

There is a quote from 3.4.3.1/1:

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the
>   name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the
>   scope of the class

But further in the 3.4.3.1/1 said:

> The name shall represent one or more members of that class or of one
>   of its base classes

And the 3.3.8/1 said:

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of
>   the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration, but
>   also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   exception-specifications, and brace-or-equal-initializers of
>   non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

This implies that base classes does not included into the derived class scope. And the 3.4.3.1/1 shall be remade to:

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the
>   name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the
>   scope of the class and **in the scope of it base classes**.

Am I right?

Comment: a small code example would go a long way to understanding the question!

Comment: @TemplateRex I think that there is no suitable code example :). My quiestion is pure theoretical.

Comment: There should be a code example where one interpretation finds a different name than another interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, you are not correct.

What you are forgetting is that it's specified that name-lookup in the scope of a class includes looking at names declared in direct bases of said class, as is stated in `10.2p5`.

> `10.2p5` **Member name lookup** `[class.member.lookup]`
>
> > Otherwise (ie., `C` does not contain a declaration of `f`or the resulting declaration set is empty), *`S(F,C)`* is initialliy empty. If `C` has base classes, calculate the lookup set for `f` in each direct base class subobject *`B_i`* and merge each suck lookup set *`S(F,B_i)`*, in turn into *`S(F,C)`*.

---

#### Simple explanation

The previous quotation might look overly complex, but it's describing the method in which a name `f` is looked up in the scope of `C`. If no declaration within `C` has the name `f`, search will continue to include those names declared in any direct bases of `C`.

( **Note**: The wording is recursive, if the name `f` isn't found in a direct base of `C`, the potential bases of bases of `C` are also search for `f` )

Comment: Did you mean that the quote `If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the scope of the class` must be interpreted as the first scope to be looking for declrartion is the class, explicitly nominated by _nested-name-spcifier_. If there is no suitable declration found, then lookup continue in the scope of base classes, if any. Did I understand you correct?